# Insert single row of values in a single column of a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Take this example query:

```
INSERT INTO #QueryOutput 
   SELECT DISTINCT 
      UR2.LeftID, UR3.LeftID  
   FROM 
      UserRelations UR1 
   JOIN 
      UserRelations UR2 ON UR1.RightID =  UR2.LeftID 
   JOIN 
     UserRelations UR3 ON UR2.RightID =  UR3.LeftID  
   WHERE 
     (UR1.RelationID = 1) 
     OR (UR1.RelationID = 1 AND UR2.RelationID = 1) 
     AND UR1.LeftID IN (SELECT UserID FROM #QueryInput)
```

With this being the magic row:

```
INSERT INTO #QueryOutput SELECT DISTINCT UR2.LeftID ,UR3.LeftID
```

`#QueryOutput` is a table with a single column, UserID

I want to insert `UR2.LeftID`, `UR3.LeftID`, or as many `UR*.LeftID`'s I have in that single column. How do go about doing that?

Thanks

Comment: How are you going to fit two values into one column? Are you looking for a way to "pivot" the values, so that the multiple columns become multiple rows instead?

Comment: Yes, a way to pivot the values into a single column. I am just not good with SQL, and I don't fully understand pivoting :(

Comment: As written, your entire WHERE condition matches its first predicate, i.e. you could rewrite it as `WHERE UR1.RelationID = 1` with same results. It's because `X ∨ X ∧ whatever ≡ X`. Something may be missing in the query's logic (or in the version you've posted here).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later I think the best way to do this is to unpivot using [cross apply](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and a [table valued constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd776382.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO #QueryOutput 
SELECT  DISTINCT upvt.LeftID
FROM    UserRelations UR1 
        JOIN UserRelations UR2 
            ON UR1.RightID =  UR2.LeftID 
        JOIN UserRelations UR3 
            ON UR2.RightID =  UR3.LeftID
        CROSS APPLY (VALUES (UR2.LeftID), (UR3.LeftID )) AS upvt (LeftID)
WHERE   (UR1.RelationID = 1 ) 
OR      (UR1.RelationID = 1 AND UR2.RelationID = 1 ) 
AND     UR1.LeftID IN (SELECT UserID FROM #QueryInput)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
INSERT INTO #QueryOutput
    SELECT DISTINCT (case when n.n = 2 then UR2.LeftID 
                          when n.n = 3 then UR3.LeftID
                     end)
    FROM UserRelations UR1 JOIN
         UserRelations UR2
         ON UR1.RightID =  UR2.LeftID JOIN
         UserRelations UR3
         ON UR2.RightID =  UR3.LeftID CROSS JOIN
         (select 2 as n union all select 3) n 
    WHERE (UR1.RelationID = 1 ) OR (UR1.RelationID = 1 AND UR2.RelationID = 1 ) AND
          UR1.LeftID IN (SELECT UserID FROM #QueryInput);
```

Comment: I don't understand the .n. code, sorry. How does it work? If possible I would only like to change the first row of my query. The From and Where parts should remain as they are... Also, there may be more than just 2 values.I could have UR1.LeftID, UR2.LeftID, ... UR*.LeftID. I have no idea how that'd increment..Since I have to auto-generate the query in code :(

Comment: This is doing an unpivot to get each value separately.  I don't think you can do this just by changing the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it's not possible except if you try doing a `UNION ALL` like below

```
INSERT INTO #QueryOutput

SELECT DISTINCT UR2.LeftID FROM UserRelations UR1 
JOIN UserRelations UR2 ON UR1.RightID =  UR2.LeftID 
JOIN UserRelations UR3 ON UR2.RightID =  UR3.LeftID  WHERE (UR1.RelationID = 1 ) 
OR (UR1.RelationID = 1 AND UR2.RelationID = 1 ) 
AND UR1.LeftID IN (SELECT UserID FROM #QueryInput)

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT UR3.LeftID FROM UserRelations UR1 
JOIN UserRelations UR2 ON UR1.RightID =  UR2.LeftID 
JOIN UserRelations UR3 ON UR2.RightID =  UR3.LeftID  WHERE (UR1.RelationID = 1 ) 
OR (UR1.RelationID = 1 AND UR2.RelationID = 1 ) 
AND UR1.LeftID IN (SELECT UserID FROM #QueryInput)
```

Comment: Would this produce the exact same result as the table I suggested to start with? And can I use as many Union Alls I want for an arbitrary X amount of tables? Thank you.

Comment: It should ... essentially you are pulling all the different `LeftID` into single column of temp table and yes you can use as many union all.